# Buttering up the Brainless — Social checks on unintelligent npcs?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills

Does Pathfinder have options for using Diplomacy to befriend or interact mindless creatures, such as oozes, zombies, golems or plants? What about Intimidate checks for instructing these sorts? If it does, what are they?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Diplomacy** have a built-in limit:

> You cannot use Diplomacy against a creature that does not understand you or has an Intelligence of 3 or less.

So, you can use it on Ooze, Brain - it has Int, telepathy 100ft and language. But it is exceptional ooze, no longer mindless.

For Plants, you can try [Awaken](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/awaken) them, and then use this skill as normal.

Certain Driud variants can use Wild Empathy (works as Diplomacy) on other things than animals. For example, [Cave Druid](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/archetypes/paizo---druid-archetypes/cave-druid) can influence oozes. [Greater Wild Empathy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/greater-wild-empathy) feat extends Wild Empathy on elementals, fey, lycanthropes, plants, or vermin (select one each time you take this feat).

Probably there are many more class variants and feats to unlock specific types for interaction. [Vermin Heart](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/vermin-heart) is a good feat to use as a base, if you need to create custom ones with your DM.

If you don't mind backporting feats from D&D 3.5, Undead Empathy feat (Eberron Campaign Setting, p. 61) is also worth noting. It is not restricted to Druids, so may be useful as template for non-druid feats. I don't know what's license on it, so will not quote, but it allows to use Diplomacy on undead. Even mindless, if not that effective. And extends normal Diplomacy rules to add "do not attack me" use - in core rules (both Pathfinder and D&D) Diplomacy is of no use against creatures already trying to attack.

---

**Intimidate** does not have any specific requirement about intelligence or anything. Form the in-world point of view it makes sense. House fly is a vermin, and you can intimidate it and make it fly away from your food, right? The only things needed are that target creature can notice what you do, and interpret it as a danger. Flies and spiders (vermin) can do it. Modern robots (constructs) can do it. **There is no general reason it would not work on creatures in a fantasy world.** Specific creatures may be, of course, immune, and you would need to know what exactly this creature will interpret as danger (see Knowledge skills) but details like that will always be up to DM.

Comment: Command Undead, This spell allows you a degree of control over an undead creature. If the subject is intelligent, it perceives your words and actions favorably (treat its attitude as friendly). It will not attack you while the spell lasts. It is along the same lines only you influence via spell. Because of this you can assume that undead can be influenced normally as if the spell was simply a 'charm' for undead.

Comment: @DanceSC magic is always a way and there is magic for everything in Pathfinder, but i believe it's a bit to far from the topic of using social **skills**.

Comment: @molot not at all, because it is used just as Charm is used for humanoid creatures. The fact that you can influence a zombies attitude and actions means that they are capable of being intimidated and influenced outside of the spell.

Comment: @DanceSC you can make stone walk with right spell, but does it prove anything about walking stones outside the spell? I don't believe so. The very point of magic is to make impossible possible.

Comment: @Molot I am not seeing your point or how stones walking is relevant in anyway to the discussion. Could you reference the spell you are referring to?

Comment: @DanceSC for example, [Animate Objects](www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/animate-objects) allows you to make objects move on their own. But that does not mean you can make objects move on their own without magic. Command undead and Control Undead allows you to affect undead - using one of two (related) kinds of magic. But that does not mean you can do it without magic. Simple as that. Chair can't walk. Mindless undead can't be talked to. With appropriate magic, both can. That's all to it, unless some **other** rule is in play. But then, that other rule is what matters.

Comment: I am interested only in skills applications (thus the tag). Spells facilitating a skill is one thing, but replacing it (as with Command Undead) is another. This would remove the skill use from the situation entirely, annulling the need for a question at all. Molot, you mentioned that Diplomacy cannot be used with creatures that are already attacking you, but a character could Intimidate someone who is attacking them into stopping, and then use Diplomacy to change the situation, right?

Comment: @Ammutseba seems right. You can intimidate to stop attack as far as I remember (can't really check now, sorry) and once he is not in combat with you or yours, diplomacy will work and you can improve attitude.