# Name of a feat, race, or something else that lets a character intimidate more types of monsters in Pathfinder

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I remember reading the Pathfinder SRD a year or two ago and seeing something that let a character intimidate monsters that normally couldn't be intimidated. I think it expanded the range to cover additional races, but it might have overcome immunity or something like that. I think it was either a feat or a racial quality, but it could have been an item quality or something else. I've spent two days looking and I can't find it again.

Does anyone remember what does this and what it is called?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a moment to check out the [tour] and the [help] to get an idea of how things work.

Comment: The Intimidate skill itself mentions nothing about it being unusable on certain creatures, yet some creatures *are* immune to fear. Can you try to remember what kinds of creatures you think are immune to the skill Intimidation? (Aside to Potential Answerers: Did *Pathfinder* change from *3.5* that the Intimidate skill is a fear effect and that all fear effects are also mind-affecting effects?)

Comment: Related: [Are undead immune to intimidate/demoralize](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/36906)

Comment: Related: [Buttering up the Brainless — Social checks on unintelligent npcs?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/50491)

Answer (score 4):

There is one class ability(that I'm aware of) that, within ten feet of itself, allows for inducing fear effects upon targets normally immune to fear(including Constructs, Oozes, Plants, Undead and Vermin)

It is the Anti-paladin's **[Aura of Cowardice](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advanced/coreClasses/paladin.html#aura-of-cowardice) (Su):**

> At 3rd level, an antipaladin radiates a palpably daunting aura that causes all enemies within 10 feet to take a –4 penalty on saving throws against fear effects. Creatures that are normally immune to fear lose that immunity while within 10 feet of an antipaladin with this ability. This ability functions only while the antipaladin remains conscious, not if he is unconscious or dead.